# Help needed to define a constraint in an optimization problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints

Given objective function is
\begin{align} 
\underset{\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}}{\text{min}}\hspace{4mm} (\mathbf{p*q})^T \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{p*q}) \hspace{4mm} \\ s.t \hspace{4mm}\mathbf{p^Te_p}-1=0\\\mathbf{q^Te_q}-1=0 \tag{1}
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{*}$ represents discrete-time convolution and $\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_p\times 1}$ and $\mathbf{q}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_q\times 1}$

I am defining $\mathbf{e_p}$ (*dim*: $n_p \times 1$)

\begin{align} 
\mathbf{e_p^T} = \begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

and $\mathbf{e_q}$ (*dim*: $n_q \times 1$)

\begin{align} 
\mathbf{e_q^T} = \begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

$n=n_p+n_q-1$. Moreover $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and has an eigen value decomposition $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{V}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{V}^T$.

*FACT:*
The convolution of $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_x \times 1}$ and $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_y \times 1}$ is equivalent to a Toeplitz matrix times a vector i-e

\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{x*y} = \mathbf{Xy}=\mathbf{Yx}=\mathbf{y*x}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{X}(dim: n\times n_y), \mathbf{Y}(dim: n\times n_x)$ are toeplitz matrices generated from vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ respectively. And $n=n_x+n_y-1$

My approach to solve (1) using ***Alternate Directional Minimization***:

1. Initialize $\mathbf{q}$ as a random vector with $q_1=1$.
2. From $\mathbf{q}$ in step:1, create a toeplitz matrix $\mathbf{Q}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ .
3. Now solve following for $\mathbf{p}$

\begin{align} 
\underset{\mathbf{p}}{\text{min}}\hspace{4mm} \mathbf{p}^T \mathbf{Q^TAQ}\mathbf{p} \hspace{4mm} \\ s.t \hspace{4mm}\mathbf{p^Te_p}-1=0 \tag{3}
\end{align}

But $\mathbf{p}$ in (3) has to have a dimension $n\times 1$ instead of $n_p\times 1$ as defined in (1) originally. This is fine as long as last $n_q-1$ entries in $\mathbf{p}$ are zero.

My questions are:

1. Is this reformulation of (1) as (3) correct?
2. How do I force last $(n_q-1)$ entries in $\mathbf{p}$ to be zero. How should I write it as a constraint.

***Update:***

For my second question, I think its enough to take a $\mathbf{Z}$ as $n_p \times n_p$ leading sub-matrix of $\mathbf{Q^TAQ}$ and solve

\begin{align} 
\underset{\mathbf{p}}{\text{min}}\hspace{4mm} \mathbf{p}^T \mathbf{Z}\mathbf{p} \hspace{4mm} \\ s.t \hspace{4mm}\mathbf{p^Te_p}-1=0 \tag{3}
\end{align}

Can some one comment on this update?

Comment: In the phase when solving for p, you can add a regularizing term $M\|p\|$ where M is a diagonal matrix with tiny positive values for the values that should be allowed to deviate and big values for those who shouldn't. The norm should probably be something that gives more sparseness than $L_2$.

Comment: Why is $Q$ $n \times n$? I think the Toeplitz matrix should be rectangular $n \times n_p$ in this case.