# Reference Request: Matrix Notation Role Swap

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

It is customary to use matrix notation to find the intersection of two lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the special case,

$$ax + by = c$$
$$bx + ay = d$$
$$x,y \in \mathbb{R}; a,b,c,d > 0$$

One would write,

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d\end{bmatrix}
$$

Due to the pattern in the coefficients of x and y, one could also write:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & x \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix}
$$

Applying Cramer's rule to the second matrix (barring some mistake), one obtains the following equations:

$$
\left(x-\frac{c}{2a}\right)^{2}-\left(y-\frac{d}{2a}\right)^{2}=\frac{\left(c^{2}-d^{2}\right)}{4a^{2}}
$$
$$
\left(x-\frac{d}{2b}\right)^{2}-\left(y-\frac{c}{2b}\right)^{2}=\frac{\left(d^{2}-c^{2}\right)}{4b^{2}}
$$

A plot of the resulting hyperbolas, as well as the original lines, is available on this [interactive graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/81pzd1kbaz). As you can see from the plot:

- Each line in the original system has two axis-intercepts and it shares both intercepts with both hyperbolas in an alternating manner. That is, the first line (containing $ax$) shares its x-intercept with the first hyperbola (containing $c/2a$), and it's y-intercept with the second hyperbola (containing $d/2b$). The second line has the reverse relationship.
- The solution to the original equation (the point where the lines intersect) is also one of the points where the hyperbolas intersect.

For those that are curious, I extended this approach to a different system (the second equation is replaced with $ax^2 + by^2 = d$), and obtained other intersecting geometries. These curves are also available at the above link, but are turned off by default.

Clearly there is a relationship between the geometries of these two representations, and this approach can be used to generate families of curves with very specific properties. **Question:** has anyone published an exploration of the consequences of re-writing the system this way, and extending it to other problems (e.g. starting from hyperbolas and working backwards)?

Note: this approach does not appear to have obvious applications for solving the original system (i.e. I have not yet found a use for the eigenvalues of the alternative representation, except that they are closely related to the determinant), and a couple of mathematician friends have informed me that this might explain why I haven't found other examples of this approach just yet.

**-------- Edit: Example derivations with Cramer's Rule --------**

Cramer's Rule enables one to solve for each component of the unknown vector by taking the ratio of a modified matrix and the original coefficient matrix.

**Original System:**

In order to solve for the first term in the vector of unknowns, the numerator of the ratio of determinants uses a matrix where the first column in the coefficient matrix is replaced by the resultant vector.
$$
x = \frac{ 
det \begin{vmatrix} c & b \\ d & a \end{vmatrix}
}{
det \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{vmatrix}
}
= \frac {ca - db}{a^2 - b^2}
$$

Since the coefficients are known, one obtains the value of x.

**Alternate System:**

Similarly, for the first value of the vector (which is known in this case),
$$
a = \frac{ 
det \begin{vmatrix} c & y \\ d & x \end{vmatrix}
}{
det \begin{vmatrix} x & y \\ y & x \end{vmatrix}
}
= \frac {cx - dy}{x^2 - y^2}
$$

From there,
$$
ax^2 - ay^2 = cx - dy
$$
Re-arrange terms,
$$
ax^2 - cx = ay^2 - dy
$$
Divide across by $a$,
$$
x^2 - \frac{c}{a}x = y^2 - \frac{d}{a}y
$$
Then complete the squares,
$$
x^2 - \frac{c}{a}x + \frac{c^2}{4a^2} - \frac{c^2}{4a^2} = y^2 - \frac{d}{a}y + \frac{d^2}{4a^2} - \frac{d^2}{4a^2}
$$
Simplify,
$$
\left(x - \frac{c}{2a} \right) ^2 - \frac{c^2}{4a^2} = \left(y - \frac{d}{2a} \right) ^2 - \frac{d^2}{4a^2}
$$
Re-arrange terms,
$$
\left(x - \frac{c}{2a} \right) ^2 - \left(y - \frac{d}{2a} \right) ^2 = \frac{c^2}{4a^2} - \frac{d^2}{4a^2}
$$

**-------- Edit 2: Derivations without Cramer's Rule 2D --------**

The way to solve the 2D system without matrix algebra is by substitution. The first step is to multiply each equation by the "other" uncommon constant:

$$
\left( ax+by \right) d =\left( c \right) d
$$
$$
\left( bx+ay \right) c =\left( d \right) c
$$
The equations can be set equal to each other, and after re-arranging, one gets,
$$
\left( ad - bc \right) x = \left( ac - bd \right) y
$$
Since we have the benefit of knowing what we're looking for, we can perform the following substitutions,
$$
x = \frac{\left( ac - bd \right)}{D}, y = \frac{\left( ad - bc \right)}{D}
$$
Substituting $D$ into either equation of the original system and solving for $D$, one quickly finds that $D = a^2 - b^2$ as expected. Thus, we have re-invented the wheel.

Similarly, to generate the hyperbolas, rather than multiplying by the "other" constant, multiply by the variables as follows:
$$
\left( ax+by \right) x =\left( c \right) x
$$
$$
\left( bx+ay \right) y =\left( d \right) y
$$

This is one connection to convolution (i.e. multiplying by polynomials). Since the coefficients on the left-hand side are the same, we will obtain terms that enable substitution on the left hand side as shown in this slightly re-arranged result:
$$
bxy = cx - ax^2
$$
$$
bxy = dy - ay^2
$$
Clearly, by substitution we obtain the intermediate step seen earlier in the Cramer's rule derivations:
$$
cx - ax^2 = dy - ay^2
$$
If I proceed with completing the squares, etc., I obtain one of the hyperbola equations I presented earlier. Alternatively, if I "solve for $a$", then I obtain,
$$
a = \frac{cx - dy}{x^2 - y^2}
$$
which is Cramer's rule for the alternate formulation. To obtain the second hyperbola equation, I multiply the system this way instead:
$$
\left( ax+by \right) y =\left( c \right) y
$$
$$
\left( bx+ay \right) x =\left( d \right) x
$$
That is, I simply reverse the multiplication (1st equation times y rather than x).

***NOTE***: this also explains why the hyperbolas share their intercepts with the lines in the original system (the linear term is preserved in the multiplication and becomes a factor of the hyperbola).

Comment: @JeanMarie: The size of the system is just to facilitate discussion. The pattern in the coefficients is of interest to me because there are equations in physics that possess this characteristic. Ultimately, my goal is to understand how far I can push the matrix notation in order to gain new insights into those equations. So my real questions are: How far can I go with this alternative formulation without introducing a fallacy? What do the new quantities represent? How do they relate to the original solution (and the original system), if at all?

Comment: @JeanMarie I will provide details tomorrow :)

Comment: @JeanMarie - Derivations added :)

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the following $3 \times 3$ system on which it is easier to see the possible generalization :

$$\begin{cases}ax+by+cz&=&u\\
cx+ay+bz&=&v\\
bx+cy+az&=&w\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

It can be written under two different matricial forms :

$$\text{Either }\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\c&a&b\\b&c&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\text{or} \ \ \ \ \ \begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\\y&z&x\\z&x&y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}\tag{2'}$$

The hidden mathematical property behind these two equivalent matrix representations is the fact that these "forward vs. backwards" **circulant matrices** correspond to **discrete (circular) convolution** $\star$, here :

$$\text{Either} \ \underbrace{(a, b, c)}_{\to \text{matrix}} \star \underbrace{(x,y,z)}_{\to \text{vector}} = \underbrace{(u,v,w)}_{\to \text{vector}} \ \text{or} \ \ \underbrace{(x, y, z)}_{\to \text{matrix}} \star \underbrace{(a,b,c)}_{\to \text{vector}} = \underbrace{(u,v,w)}_{\to \text{vector}} $$

Indeed, convolution corresponds to the first signal $abc$ (periodized) sliding *to the right* over the second one $xyz$ with, at each step, a totalization of products of corresponding terms.

Dualy, one can consider that it is the second signal, $xyz$ which slides *to the left* in front of the first one, explaining the structure of the second matrix in (2).

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}a&b&c&a&b&c\\ \hline&&&x&y&z\end{array} \ \ \ \text{see equ. (1)i)}$$

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}a&b&c&a&b&c\\ \hline&&x&y&z&\end{array}  \ \ \ \text{see equ. (1)ii)}$$

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}a&b&c&a&b&c\\ \hline&x&y&z&&\end{array}  \ \ \ \text{see equ. (1)iii)}$$

For more, see [here](https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2014/02/survey-of-methods-to-compute-convolution/).

Remark : I don't address in this analysis the hyperbolas representation, just because I have no idea of the way one the $2 \times 2$ case could be generalized.

Comment: See as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807393/help-needed-to-define-a-constraint-in-an-optimization-problem)

Comment: This is phenomenal! I'll need a little time to read the links and think carefully about your answer. I really appreciate the time and effort you put into it!

Comment: The article on convolution is interesting and makes sense. I will show how to derive the hyperbolas for the 2x2 without Cramer's Rule, and then will show how I would extend the matrix multiplication into 3x3 (though the result will no longer be hyperbolas). I'll need time, but hopefully I can come back to this within the next week or so.

Comment: Question: are you saying you're sure how the convolution connection would generalize to the 3x3 case?

Comment: The convolution connection works for the general $n$ case.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. The key to the notation swap is the fact that there are only $n$ coefficients on the left-hand side, just as there are $n$ unknowns in the $n \times n$ system of equations. There is an upper bound on the number of such matrices I could write (by just re-arranging coefficients), and some of them are Toeplitz matrices, but they do not have to be.

Comment: The 3D derivations seem to require 2 multiplications rather than 1, and are much messier. I'll continue for the fun of it. I think the take-away from all this is that it's clear that I can obtain families of curves with shared x and y intercepts. So this could be a way to transform one problem into a related problem. What is not yet clear to me is how the other well-known linear algebra tools can be used to achieve other insights.

Comment: I am still asking myself too how the extension 2D $\to$ 3D of your hyperbolas could be achieved : by intersection of 3 hyperboloids (or more generally 3 quadrics) ? But from where could they come from